# Is there an alternative for `proxy_options` now that it's been removed? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 2 you could use `proxy_options` to see the options for specific database queries. In rails 3 it has been removed. Is there a different option for getting this same info?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025103/how-to-test-a-scope-in-rails-3

Comment: Not a dupe, the linked question is about how to test a scope. My question is about knowing what the scoped query looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a long answer here: [How to test a scope in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025103/how-to-test-a-scope-in-rails-3)

But the main answer is use #where_values_hash or #to_sql on your scope.

Comment: Or `where_values`. So you might do: `User.joins(:address).where(Address.foreign.where_values)`.

Comment: Note: `where_values_hash` doesn't seem to work everywhere; doesn't work when chained with `not` (including scopes chained as such). Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23613 (doesn't look like it's being worked on at this time)

Answer (score 1):

I only now [learned](http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/) of a nicer way. Undocumented but nice:

```
User.joins(:address).merge(Address.foreign)
```

as an alternative to

```
User.joins(:address).where(Address.foreign.where_values)
```