# refactoring model to remove proxy_options for rails 3 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-activerecord

I'm currently upgrading a rails app from 2.x to 3.1.

Wondering if anyone can help to refactor this to remove the proxy_option code (which is no longer available in rails 3):

```
scope = Product.scoped({})
scope = scope.scoped( Product.allowed(options[:current_user]).proxy_options )
scope = scope.scoped( Product.for_country(options[:country_ids]).proxy_options ) if options[:country_ids]
```

Example of one of the scope methods include:

```
  def allowed(user)
    where(:id => user.access_to(self.name))
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a possible solution: [Is there an alternative for `proxy_options` now that it's been removed? rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654191/is-there-an-alternative-for-proxy-options-now-that-its-been-removed-rails)

Seems like the code is building up an SQL query and rather than replacing the method you may have to replace the concept by figuring out what each line is trying to do and using Rails 3 scope or Arel to get the same results.

Perhaps copy the output SQL from Rails 2.x put it into a test and just make sure you Rails 3 code produces the same SQL query with the same params.