# How can i have rspec test for my default scope

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, scope, default-scope

my model has default_scope(:order => 'created_at' )
my tests (rspec, factory girl, shoulda, etc.)
are:

```
require 'spec/spec_helper.rb'

describe CatMembership do
  context "is valid" do
    subject { Factory.build(:cat_membership) }
    it { should be_valid }
    it { should belong_to :cat}
    it { should belong_to :cat_group}
    it { should have_db_column(:start_date)}
    it { should have_db_column(:end_date)}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would rather have this tested using a query and checking the results, but if you really must do it, one possible solution would be something like this for Rails 3:

```
CatMembership.scoped.to_sql.should == CatMembership.order(:created_at).to_sql
```

And on Rails 2:

```
CatMembership.default_scoping.should == [{:create=>{}, :find=>{:order=>"created_at"}}]
```

But I would not say these solutions are ideal since they show a lot of knowledge of the implementation (and you can see the implementation varies with different Rails versions).

Creating sample data, running an usual **all** query and checking the result is correctly ordered might have been simpler, would be closer to real unit testing and would work even as you upgrade your rails version.

In this case it would possibly be:

```
before do
  @memberships = []

  @memberships << CatMembership.create!
  @memberships << CatMembership.create!
  @memberships << CatMembership.create!

  [ 1.hour.ago, 5.minutes.ago, 1.minute.ago ].each_with_index do |time, index|
    membership = @memberships[index]
    membership.created_at = time
    membership.save
  end

end

it 'should be correctly ordered' do
  @sorted_memberships = CatMembership.all
  @memberships.first.should == @sorted_memberships.last
  @memberships.second.should == @sorted_memberships.second
  @memberships.third.should == @sorted_memberships.first
end
```

It's much more verbose, but it's going to work even as you move forward on rails.

And now I have just noticed who asked the question :D

Comment: +1 - Mauricio's example specifies behavior, whereas Michael's example specifies structure.

Comment: Hi David, great comment.  I think I want to do both really.  Have tests for the basic structure to make sure things don't get renamed, changed, etc.  But also I would like to test whether it is really getting 'enforced' the way I have structured it, so Mauricio's example is great for that.  I will also look to implement the first line Mauricio has given as that should help with structure

Comment: I really like Mauricio's first line to address the structure.  However when I have added   context "scope is valid" do
    subject { GorillaMembership.scoped.to_sql == GorillaMembership.order(:created_at).to_sql }
    it {should be_valid}
  end   I get NoMethodError: undefined method `valid?' for false:FalseClass

Comment: There isn't a method available, you have to use that line as it is inside an **it** block.

Comment: Hi Mauricio I tried and tried to get it (the structure, scope_to) bit working but every combination gave issues. I will have to return to this in the future.  Last try was:  context "scope is valid" do
    pending { GorillaMembership.scoped.to_sql == GorillaMembership.order(:created_at).to_sql }
    it {should be_valid}
  end

Comment: or rather:   context "scope is valid" do
    subject { GorillaMembership.scoped.to_sql == GorillaMembership.order(:start_date).to_sql }
    it {should == true}
  end

Answer (score 3):

### DRY It Up, Use Shared Examples

Most likely, you'll have more than one model with a similar default scope (if not, mostly ignore this method) so you can put this Rspec example into a shared_example where you can call it from a variety of model specs.

My preferred method of checking a default scope is to make sure the default `ActiveRecord::Relation` has the expected clause (`order` or `where` or whatever the case may be), like so:

**spec/support/shared_examples/default_scope_examples.rb**

```
shared_examples_for 'a default scope ordered by created_at' do

  it 'adds a clause to order by created_at' do
    described_class.scoped.order_clauses.should include("created_at")
  end

end
```

And then in your `CatMembership` spec (and any other spec that has the same default scope), all you need to is:

**spec/models/cat_membership_spec.rb**

```
describe CatMembership

  it_behaves_like 'a default scope ordered by created_at'

  # other spec examples #

end
```

Finally, you can see how this pattern can be extended to all sorts of default scopes and keeps things clean, organized and, best of all, DRY.

Answer (score 0):

According to latest conventions of `RSpec` `expect` is recommended instead of `should` so, better answer would be

`expect(CatMembership.scoped.to_sql).to eq(CatMembership.order(:created_at).to_sql)`

However, lately `Model.scoped` is deprecated so it is recommended to use `Model.all` instead

`expect(CatMembership.all.to_sql).to eq(CatMembership.order(:created_at).to_sql)`